# Date/Time Picker unable to loop properly

Tags: c#, slideshow, datetimepicker

Want to do a loop of picture slideshow to start from a specific time and then to end at another specific time.

Also, how to set the DateTime picker to select minutes/hours?

```
//Under start button    
 if (rbtnDateTime.Checked == true)
{
    DateTime startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
    DateTime stopDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;

    //Given time interval in seconds
    if (mtxtSlideShowInterval.Text != "")
    {
        int interval = Convert.ToInt16(mtxtSlideShowInterval.Text);
        while ((startDate = startDate.AddSeconds(interval)) <= stopDate)
        {
            timerSlideShow.Enabled = true;
            timerSlideShow.Start();
        }
            timerSlideShow.Stop();
            timerSlideShow.Enabled = false;
    }
}

//Under timer_tick event
//Infinite Loop
        else
        {

            if (listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedIndex ==listBoxPicturesInAlbum.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedIndex++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's not working? What are you hoping to accomplish that this code doesn't do?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Currently when I click the button and I debug, the code runs with no errors but the picturebox doesn't show the listbox selecteditem. Also, how to set the DateTimePicker to be able to set the hour/minute/second?

Comment: Well, your `while` loop will take "zero" time to execute, as it stands. And starting your `timerSlideShow` inside that `while` loop doesn't make a lot of sense. I'm not really sure I see why you need the `while` loop at all.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Sorry, beginner at programming here... How to I set so that it'll wait till the timer_tick event fires before the loop continues?

Comment: No problem. I've posted an answer that will hopefully help guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be rid of the `while` loop you have, and take a few steps.

First, you'll need a field to mark your current index:

```
int currentImageIndex = 0;
```

Second, you'll set your `timer.Interval`.

```
timer.Interval = int.Parse(mtxtSlideShowInterval.Text) * 1000;
```

Third, your `timer_tick` can include something like this:

```
if (DateTime.Now < dateTimePicker2.Value.Date)
{
    listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedIndex = currentImageIndex;
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile((string)listBoxPicturesInAlbum.SelectedValue);

    currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % listBoxPicturesInAlbum.Items.Count;
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible for dateTimePicker2.Value.Date to have hours, minutes and seconds? Like i can set the hour,minute and seconds in the dateTimePicker window. Thanks

Comment: @SGKawe yeah. I'm not near MSDN right now so I can't get you the right property names, and it's been a while since I did this, but I believe you need to change the custom format property to whatever you want the format to be, then change like "display" or something to tell it to use the custom format.